# Django admin order field doesn't look right

Tags: django, django-admin

My django admin panel doesn't seem to be sorting correctly, I have a custom method which will count the comments of each post.

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'comments', 'created')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PostAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(com=models.Count('comment'))
        return qs

    def comments(self, obj):
        return obj.comment_set.count()

    comments.admin_order_field = 'com'
```

But sadly, whenever I click the header of the table to sort by comments, I get something like this:

```
85
100
132
128
36
```

Yes, I've made sure to sort the column by descending order.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add extra filters to it? The `def comments(self, obj)`, should return `obj.com`, not `obj.comment_set.count()` since then you "undo" the filtering of the related field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `comments` method as:

`def comments(self, obj):
    return obj.com`